# A framework for animating a network graph algorithm in Python

Tags: python, animation, vector-graphics

I’m looking for a way to animate a network graph algorithm in Python.

What I need to do is to draw a (large) network graph and manipulate it (add/remove vertices, add/remove edges, change vertices size and/or color, change edges colors, etc.), without having to redraw the entire graph for every frame.

I found several similar questions ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47579442/generating-network-graph-in-python) for example) but they all either regard static plotting of network graphs or are very old and the examples doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

3Blue1Brown's [manim](https://github.com/3b1b/manim) animation engine may be something to consider. It supports LaTeX-style graphics and has quite an active community.

Comment: Interesting. Any idea if it can handle a network graph with hundreds of vertices and several thousands of edges (each as a separate object)?

Comment: In terms of rendering power, I'm sure it could handle many more than thousands of nodes and edges. However, it does not natively carry any graph tools. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aircAruvnKk&ab_channel=3Blue1Brown) is an example of large graph rendering by the creator himself.

Comment: Thanks, I'll definitely check it out!